# How to apply background gradient in FAB component of paper?

Tags: react-native, floating-action-button, linear-gradients, react-native-paper

It is possible to apply a gradient background in the FAB component of the paper with https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient?

Or is there another way to apply a gradient background in the fab, or does it only accept a solid color?

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/fab.html

[FAB solid color example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMkcU.jpg)

**EDIT:**
I solved it somehow.

I put the Linear gradient, but without children, I solved it with CSS.

The gradient has the same format as the Fab and is on top, the FAB.Group has a transparent background and elevation: 99

Comment: You need to wrap FAB in ```LinearGradient``` Component with border radius and make FAB background transparent.

Comment: Any practical examples? when I wrap my fab.group inside a linear gradient, the fab group layout it totally breaks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this, the approach that worked is a little bit hacky, but gets the job done. You can add a LinearGradient element that underlays the FAB.

For example, in your parent component, I used `LinearGradient` underneath the FAB button, and added a dropshadow by wrapping it in another View...

```
import { Portal } from "react-native-paper";
import ActionButton from "./ActionButton";

export default function ParentComponent() {
  return (
    <Portal.Host>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView
          style={{
            flex: 1,
          }}
        >
        ....your content here
        </ScrollView>
        <View
          style={{
            ...styles.fabBase,
            ...styles.fabWrapper,
            overflow: "visible",
          }}
        >
          <LinearGradient
            style={{
              ...styles.fabBase,
            }}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
            colors={["#1BE68C", "#00C0FF"]}
          />
        </View>
        <ActionButton />
      </View>
    </Portal.Host>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fabBase: {
    width: 56,
    height: 55,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  fabWrapper: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 15.5,
    bottom: 50,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 20,
    elevation: 5,
  },
});
```

And then your `ActionButton` component may look like this - notice the `transparent` background color.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FAB } from "react-native-paper";

const ActionButton = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ open: false });

  const onStateChange = ({ open }) => setState({ open });

  const { open } = state;

  return (
    <FAB.Group
      open={open}
      visible
      mode={"elevated"}
      fabStyle={{
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
      }}
      icon={open ? "close" : "plus"}
      actions={[
        { icon: "plus", onPress: () => console.log("Pressed add") },
        {
          icon: "star",
          label: "Star",
          onPress: () => console.log("Pressed star"),
        },
        {
          icon: "email",
          label: "Email",
          onPress: () => console.log("Pressed email"),
        },
        {
          icon: "bell",
          label: "Remind",
          onPress: () => console.log("Pressed notifications"),
        },
      ]}
      onStateChange={onStateChange}
      onPress={() => {
        if (open) {
          // do something if the speed dial is open
        }
      }}
    ></FAB.Group>
  );
};

export default ActionButton;
```

Comment: Did you know you can use an array on the style attribute like this: style={[styles.fabBase, styles.fabWrapper, { borderWidth: 1, padding: 10 }]} - borderWidth and padding are just examples of how to add individual style properties in addition to the "class" type properties .fabBase and .fabWrapper instead of using the ... spread operator (...styles.fabBase, ...) which you have done - both are valid and I don't have any opinion on which is more readable - up to individual (or codebase if on an established project) style